# "had been suspended" In Google Serch

Tags: grammar

Why Google Search Shows Did you mean "has been suspended" when we put search for "had been suspended"? Is "had been suspended" is grammatically incorrect?

Comment: Are you asking about Google or about the grammar? I doubt any of us are Google employees, or, if we were, could divulge its algorithms. The phrase itself is grammatical.

Answer (score 4):

"Had been suspended" is a fragment. It would be a correct part of a sentence such as "John had been suspended". It is simply the past perfect tense.

The present perfect is used much more often than the past perfect, and the Google algorithm offers the present perfect tense as an alternative that gets more hits than the past in this case. Google is a search engine, not a grammar checker.